# Any way to select tables from an array in SQL?

Tags: sql

I'm looking to get an output which takes the MAX last_updated_at timestamp from every table in a schema I'm looking at and then union'ing those into one output.

My ideal output would be:
TABLE NAME | MAX(LAST_UPDATED_AT)

Since my database has 3000 tables, is there a way I could do this without using 2999 UNIONs?

Comment: What DBMS are you currently using?

Comment: I would rather think about whether 3000 tables indicate a poor database design.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.